# Do you work directly in the Github respository folder?

Tags: python, git, github

I recently started using Github and was wondering if I should be working directly in the Github repository folder, or working in a different folder and then adding new files to the repository later?

Comment: Usually you clone a repository from Github on your own computer which also creates a working copy with the latest revision of all files in repository. Then you work with this working copy, commit changes and from time to time push changes back to Github and pull changes from there.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow. See: [help/on-topic]. You can **plenty** of information on Git and GitHub online.

Answer (score -1):

GitHub is a code hosting platform for version control and collaboration. It lets you and others work together on projects from anywhere and you can create one branch for you and update it to master branch.

Comment: This does not answer OP’s question at all.